# Deploying SSAS Tabular in a remote server with ODBC DSN

Tags: hive, odbc, ssas-tabular, dsn

I am deploying a SSAS Tabular project that uses a ODBC datasource.
This datasource is a DSN created for Hive (cloudera).
I am using SSDT for developing the datasource. I had to install ODBC Driver for 64 and 34 bits with the same name (here the explanation https://ayadshammout.com/2013/07/13/ssas-tabular-using-hiveodbc-connection/)

I am trying to deploy this proyect in a remote server, but I get this error:
"The modifications to the server could not be saved. Error returned: 'Error de OLE DB u ODBC.
Could not connect to the data source named 'Hive_DES'"

Is it necessary that the ODBCs be created on the server with the same name?

Thanks

Comment: Now I have the same name, but y have another error: The modifications to the server could not be saved. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. It is necessary configurate an user with permissions to get data. The ODBC should be well configured.